# Actualización de documentos MongoDB utilizando un substring de uno de los campos

Tags: mongodb

Estoy intentando actualizar todos los documentos de una colección modificando uno de sus campos por un `substring` de su propio valor. Es decir, tengo una colección con `n` documentos con un campo:

```
{"codigo": "ERC3453456789654567896"}
```

Lo que quiero es actualizar todos los documentos de la colección y asignar al campo `codigo` los 20 primeros caracteres del valor, quedando de esta manera:

```
{"codigo": "ERC34534567896545678"}
```

Lo que he intentado es:

```
db.getCollection('EST').updateMany({},{$set: {"codigo": { $substr: [ "$codigo", 0, 20 ] }}})
```

pero no funciona.

Podría alguien echarme una mano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con tu [`query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/index.html) es que intentas realizar una asignación sobre un campo usando una expresión [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/index.html) propia de un proceso de [`Agregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/index.html)(que además está obsoleta si usas MongoDB 3.4 o superior).

Si leemos la documentación del método [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html), vemos que el documento que representa las modificaciones a realizar debe ser de uno de los siguientes tipos:

- Un documento que contenga expresiones de [`operador de actualización`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1).
- A partir de MongoDB 4.2, una *tubería* de agregación. La tubería puede contener las siguiente etapas:

  - [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) y su alias [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set)
  - [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) y su alias [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#pipe._S_unset)
  - [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot) y su alias [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith)

---

## Mongo 4.2+

Si usas MongoDB en su versión más actualizada (4.2 o superior) podrías lograr lo que necesitas haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
db.gtCollection('EST').updateMany({}, [
  {"$set": {
    "codigo": {"$substrBytes": ["$codigo", 0, 20]}
  }
]);
```

Como puedes ver, el documento de `update` en este caso es una etapa de agregación usando `$set`. Las etapas de agregación deben ser pasadas como documentos de un tipo `Array`. De tal forma, la etapa de agregación sería la siguiente:

```
{ "$set": { "codigo": { "$substrBytes": ["$codigo", 0, 20] } } }
```

Hay que notar que cuando nos referimos al campo al que realizaremos la asignación el mismo se escribe sin usar símbolo `$` delante del mismo, y cuando nos referimos al valor de dicho campo para realizar la operación de `$substrBytes` si le hemos colocado el símbolo `$` delante del nombre del campo.

## Mongo 2.2 hasta Mongo 4.0

Dado que en versiones previas de MongoDB no se permite usar etapas de agregación como documentos `update` en las consultas, se debe utilizar otra forma para realizar la actualización dinámica del campo.

Una forma sería utilizar el método [`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/index.html) aplicado al cursor durante una consulta de tipo `find()`. Así, por cada documento devuelto por la consulta se realiza una operación de modificación del campo y luego se procede a salvar dicho documento en la colección, completándose así la actualización requerida:

```
db.getCollection('EST').find({}).forEach((doc) => {
  doc.codigo = String(doc.codigo).substring(0,20);
  db.getCollection('EST').save(doc);
});
```

Este método actualiza cada documento de la colección `EST`. Si el documento no contiene un campo llamado `codigo`, el mismo será creado y su valor será `undefined`.

Espero que de esta forma puedas lograr lo que te propones.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque supongo que habrá alguna forma mejor, creo que lo puedes hacer así (al menos con python):

```
for doc in db.collection.find():
    doc['codigo']=doc['codigo'][:20]
    db.collection.save(doc)
```